# Firebase Hosting: is it possible to rewrite a URL and pass part of the path to Cloud Run?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I want to front an API on Cloud Run with Firebase Hosting on the `/api` prefix. So that an incoming request for `/api/something` is handled by the API `/something` handler. Seems simple but I can't figure it out, so I'm wondering if it's even possible with Firebase hosting.

First thing I've tried is:

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "my-api",
          "region": "us-central1"
        }
      }
    ]
```

This correctly routes `/api` requests to the service root `/`, but calling `/api/something` just 404s.

Second attempt was using `"source": "/api/**"` or `"regex": "/api(/.*)?",`. This correctly receives requests like `/api/something` but routes it to the API root `/` instead of `/something`.

Ideally, I would like it to strip the `/api` prefix, or allow me to use the extracted regex group on the routed url.
Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve this issue? (I assume you did not use rewrites but some other option)

Comment: I ended up not using Firebase hosting, and just using an http gateway/proxy (envoy proxy in my case) hosted on cloud run itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ideally, I would like it to strip the /api prefix, or allow me to use the extracted regex group on the routed url.

That's not going to be possible.  The full URI of the request will always be preserved and forwarded to Cloud Run.  Your code on the Cloud Run side should be able to deal with the full path as it was sent to Firebase Hosting.  If you want to strip any path prefixes, it will have to be in the code deployed to Cloud Run.

Comment: I see, not much of a rewrite, but I think I can work with that. Thanks!

Comment: In the case of sending requests to Cloud Functions or Cloud Run, it's more of a forwarding than a pure rewrite.  It seems they chose to use the existing rewrite syntax to implement this.